# Google Apps Script receive webhooks from Stripe, failed to extract part of the received event information

Tags: google-apps-script, stripe-payments, webhooks

Following up on another questions (the reply works!):
[How to use Google Apps Script to get POST request from Stripe webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299906/how-to-use-google-apps-script-to-get-post-request-from-stripe-webhooks)

I have revised my code as follow:

```
function doPost(e) {

    var jsonString = e.postData.contents;
    var event = JSON.parse(jsonString)
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("xxx");
    var timeStamp = new Date();
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(timeStamp, "GMT+08:00", "MM/dd/yy, h:mm a");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();


    //Insert the data into the sheet  
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(time);   
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(event["data"]["object"]["id"]);
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(event["data"]["object"]["amount_paid"]);
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(event["data"]["object"]["customer_email"]);
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(event["data"]["object"]["lines"]["data"]["description"]);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(200);
}
```

For the last .setValue one, I can not get the string "description", the request information is as follow:

```
{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "invoice.payment_succeeded",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": null,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "in_00000000000000",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "HK",
      "account_name": "xxx",
      "amount_due": 400,
      "amount_paid": 400,
      "amount_remaining": 0,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "attempt_count": 1,
      "attempted": true,
      "auto_advance": false,
      "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
      "charge": "_00000000000000",
      "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
      "created": 1570506796,
      "currency": "hkd",
      "custom_fields": null,
      "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
      "customer_address": null,
      "customer_email": "xxx",
      "customer_name": null,
      "customer_phone": null,
      "customer_shipping": null,
      "customer_tax_exempt": "none",
      "customer_tax_ids": [
      ],
      "default_payment_method": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "default_tax_rates": [
      ],
      "description": null,
      "discount": null,
      "due_date": null,
      "ending_balance": 0,
      "footer": null,
      "hosted_invoice_url": "xxx",
      "invoice_pdf": "xxx",
      "lines": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "il_00000000000000",
            "object": "line_item",
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "hkd",
            "description": "xxx",
            "discountable": true,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
              "code": "xxx",
              "user_id": "xxx",
              "hashId": "xxx"
            },
            "period": {
              "end": 1607183999,
              "start": 1591607019
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "plan_00000000000000",
              "object": "plan",
              "active": true,
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 10000,
              "amount_decimal": "10000",
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1591603592,
              "currency": "hkd",
              "interval": "month",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "prod_00000000000000",
              "tiers": null,
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "price": {
              "id": "plan_00000000000000",
              "object": "price",
              "active": true,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1591603592,
              "currency": "hkd",
              "livemode": false,
              "lookup_key": null,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "prod_00000000000000",
              "recurring": {
                "aggregate_usage": null,
                "interval": "month",
                "interval_count": 1,
                "usage_type": "licensed"
              },
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_quantity": null,
              "type": "recurring",
              "unit_amount": 10000,
              "unit_amount_decimal": "10000"
            },
            "proration": false,
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "sub_00000000000000",
            "subscription_item": "si_00000000000000",
            "tax_amounts": [
            ],
            "tax_rates": [
            ],
            "type": "subscription"
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "object": "list",
        "url": "xxx"
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "next_payment_attempt": null,
      "number": "xxx",
      "paid": true,
      "payment_intent": "pi_00000000000000",
      "period_end": 1570506796,
      "period_start": 1570506796,
      "post_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
      "pre_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "starting_balance": 0,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "status": "paid",
      "status_transitions": {
        "finalized_at": xxx,
        "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
        "paid_at": xxx,
        "voided_at": null
      },
      "subscription": "sub_00000000000000",
      "subtotal": 400,
      "tax": null,
      "tax_percent": null,
      "total": 400,
      "total_tax_amounts": [
      ],
      "transfer_data": null,
      "webhooks_delivered_at": 1570506798,
      "closed": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How about modifying from `event["data"]["object"]["lines"]["data"]["description"]` to `event["data"]["object"]["lines"]["data"][0]["description"]`?

Comment: It works now thanks! I am a new learner, sorry to ask what is the difference of adding a [0] in between? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you check `event["data"]["object"]["lines"]["data"]`, you can see `"data": []`. In this case, it's an array with the length of 1. So `[0]` of `event["data"]["object"]["lines"]["data"][0]` means the 1st index of the array. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Comment: Understood, thank you a lot!